# How can I make a carousel?

Tags: java, android, native, carousel

I'm looking to create a carousel that snaps to whatever page covers most of the screen after a swipe, similar to how swipes can move through pages of android shortcuts and widgets. Similar to [this](http://rawgit.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/1.1.2/tests/manual/carousel.html). Each page should be able to display any assortment of layouts, data, or pictures.

I have looked at the resources on the ["Creating an Android Image Carousel" page by Giancarlo Leonio](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aoXioT79YGV0J%3awww.verious.com/board/Giancarlo-Leonio/creating-an-android-image-carousel/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca). However, most questions are unanswered or do not apply to android.

I have seen tutorials with a viewpager, but they immediately switch pages after a swipe. I prefer that the pages appear to be connected.

Comment: That sounds exactly like the default behavior of a ViewPager. Are you sure that's not what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `ViewPager`. I don't know where you found these tutorials that lead you to believe that the interactions would appear that the pages are not interconnected.

You can find a good tutorial and demo transitions on the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Additionally, if you also want the indicators that Carousels would normally have you can take a look at the most popular library out there for ViewPagers...

- [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)
- [Sample App on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample)